# setting up the demos of actionbarsherlock on eclipse

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I downloaded the JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-88fc341 and trying to test demos of the actionbarsherlock. I was able to create a project using the library folder but when i try to create another project with demos folder as the source code it is showing up errors in one java class file. I checked it as a library and the library folder is also checked as a library. please help with setting up the demos of actionbarsherlock on eclipse

Comment: Without the errors or other details, help won't easily be provided

Comment: @dystory In the tabnavigationcollapsed java file, at first line it is showing me the following error   "Multiple markers at this line
 - The type android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction cannot be resolved. It 
  is indirectly referenced from required .class files
 - The type android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction cannot be resolved. It 
  is indirectly referenced from required .class files" I am not using the fragments folders source code. I wonder that package it is looking for is in the fragments source code.

Answer (score 15):

Perhaps your Android support library references are mismatched.

On both the ABS project and your own project remove the `/libs/android-support-v4.jar`. Then re-add the support library for each project. To do so: right click on each project -> `Android Tool` -> `Add Support Library`.

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Thank you!  I ran into this error after updating to the latest ADT version and couldn't figure it out until I read your reply here.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

The AndroidBarSherlock project should be marked as a library.
It should include the Android Support Package in its build path. (To add it: right click on the project -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library)

Your project should not be marked as a library.
In Project Properties->Android you should have a reference to AndroidBarSherlock as a library.

Answer (score 0):

As far as android-support-v4.jar library is already present in the Sherlock library, check, whether you don't have this one in your own project too. If so, delete it from your /libs folder.